# Formik handleReset is going through validation

Tags: reactjs, validation, next.js, formik

I'm trying to add a Reset button on my Formik form. Trouble is, when I click the Reset button Formik shows me the validation errors. Only after I click the Reset button a second time does the form actually reset. Why should the user go through form validation if all they want is to reset the form, right? Here's my form component:

```
const ContactForm = () => {

  const submit = async (values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
    ... submit logic ...
  }

  return (
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            name: '',
            email: '',
            message: '',
          }}
          validationSchema={Yup.object({
            name: Yup.string()
              .min(3, 'Tamanho mínimo: 3 caracteres')
              .max(20, 'Tamanho máximo: 20 caracteres')
              .required('Campo obrigatório.'),
            ...more fields ...
          })}
          onSubmit={submit}
        >
          {({ isValid, isSubmitting, handleReset }) => (
            <Form>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label">
                  Nome
                </label>
                <Field
                  name="name"
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  aria-describedby="nameHelp"
                />
                <ErrorMessage
                  component="div"
                  id="nameHelp"
                  name="name"
                  className="form-text text-warning"
                />
              </div>
              ... more fields ...
              <button
                type="submit"
                disabled={isSubmitting || !isValid}
                className="btn btn-primary shadow me-3"
              >
                Enviar
              </button>
              <button
                disabled={isSubmitting}
                className="btn btn-outline-primary shadow"
                onClick={handleReset}
              >
                Apagar
              </button>
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>
  )
}

export default ContactForm
```

I must be doing something wrong. How can I reset the form without going through the validation process?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update your reset button as follows -

```
<button type="reset"  onClick={ e => formik.resetForm()}> Reset</button>
```